# jquery slidein from under a div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, html

I am trying to achieve a certain effect using jquery ui. I have a menu div at the right end of the screen which contains links. When a user clicks on one of those links, a div comes sliding in from the right of the page and into view. I am achieving this nice effect, however there's a small nicety I would like to add to it.

When the div comes sliding in, I would like it to come from under the menu div and into view. I tried doing this by playing around with z-index values of these divs but to no effect.

I've setup a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/YYVS7/3/

How can this be done?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a small tweak that positions the menu absolutely, I'm not sure if that is what you're after but it may help you get there!

http://jsfiddle.net/YYVS7/5/

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve, but by adding

```
    margin-top:-50px;
```

to the .content class the content div appears from under the menu